# Substitute command as variable into bash script

Tags: bash, awk

I need to substitute a portion of an `awk` command in a script with different cases, from this:

```
CONTAINER=$1

RESULTS=$(ssh -o LogLevel=QUIET -t -i ~/key.pem user@server sudo docker stats --no-stream $CONTAINER | awk '{if (NR!=1) {print substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)}}')
```

to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONTAINER=$1
TYPE=$2

case "${TYPE}" in   
    cpu)
        AWK="'{if (NR!=1) {print substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)}}'"
    ;;   
esac

RESULTS=$(ssh -o LogLevel=QUIET -t -i ~/key.pem user@server sudo docker stats --no-stream $CONTAINER | awk $AWK)
```

But I always get a syntax error.

Comment: Does initial expression work good?

Comment: You need to escape the $2 since it will be interpreted by the shell before awk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a variable declaration, anything (other than parameter/command/arithmetic expansion) inside `"` is treated literally, so when you do:

```
var="'foobar'"
```

`$var` will be expanded to `'foobar'`, not `foobar`.

So you need:

```
AWK='{if (NR!=1) {print substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)}}'
```

as you don't need any pre-expansion by shell, better to use single quotes to stay on the safer side. If you use double quotes, then e.g. `$2` will be expanded beforehand by the shell as parameter expansion, this is true for any other tokens that are special to shell.

And don't forget to quote `$AWK` when you use it to disable the split+glob operator:

```
… | awk "$AWK"
```

Comment: OK thanks, my problem was the `""` to `$AWK`, thanks!